# Unable to edit /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: debian

When I try to do `apt-get update`, nothing is working. I have got info that I should edit `/etc/sources.list`, but when I try writing

```
 deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

I am unable to save the file, as I get an error saying that I cannot edit the sources list.

Comment: it's not `/etc/sources.list` that's `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Is that typo ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be root to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

**Always make a backup copy of your current sources.list file**

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

then add new line to the file,

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will prompt you for `sudo` password. Enter your password and add your line to it. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.